# cl-who: using a variable in with-html-output-to-string

Tags: macros, common-lisp, cl-who

All the examples I've seen so far for `cl-who` work like this:

```
(with-html-output-to-string (s)
   (:HTML (:HEAD (:TITLE "hello")) (:BODY (:DIV "world"))))
```

Which works fine.
However, I wanted to use `with-html-output-to-string` with a variable, instead of a hardcoded html tree; if `*p*` has `(:HTML (:HEAD (:TITLE "hello")) (:BODY (:DIV "world")))` and I do this

```
(with-html-output-to-string (s)
   *p*)
```

I get `""` as a result. 
I guess that as `with-html-output-to-string` is a macro, it's last argument is never evaluated.
Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: I was unable to add the tag `cl-who` (doesn't exist, not enough rep).

Comment: The only thing I can think of is `(eval \`(with-html-output-to-string (s) ,*p*))`. It doesn't seem like there's an implementation for `with-html-output-to-string` as a function.

Comment: there's a special construct for that: `str` - see http://weitz.de/cl-who/#example

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin that worked for me; if you want to put that in an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cl-who:str`; check the examples at http://weitz.de/cl-who/#example.

If you do:

```
(with-html-output-to-string (s)
   (str *p*))
```

you'll get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Passing around partial html trees as lisp forms is not the expected way in cl-who, but you could use some cl-who internals (apply `tree-to-commands`) to write a litte wrapper.

Comment: I found out that using `cl-who:str` suits my needs. Thanks anyway.